# After the "printingSystem1.ExportToImage (file name)", I do not want to run any software to view the images. What should I do?

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

```
/* I use of DevExpress component */       
     BrickGraphics gr = printingSystem1.Graph;
            BrickStringFormat bsf = new BrickStringFormat(StringAlignment.Near, StringAlignment.Center);
            gr.StringFormat = bsf;
            gr.BorderColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
            ImageBrick imagebrick;
            gr.Modifier = BrickModifier.Detail;
            printingSystem1.Begin();          
            Image pageimage = Image.FromFile("Data\\sorathesab.jpg");            
            printingSystem1.PageSettings.Landscape = false;
            gr.BeginUnionRect();
            // Detail section creation.
            gr.Modifier = BrickModifier.Detail;
            printingSystem1.PageSettings.LeftMargin = 5;
            printingSystem1.PageSettings.RightMargin = 5;
            printingSystem1.PageSettings.TopMargin = 5;
            printingSystem1.PageSettings.BottomMargin = 5;
            float X = gr.ClientPageSize.Width - 1, Y = gr.ClientPageSize.Height - 1;// X = 736.32, Y = 930.24;      
            printingSystem1.PageSettings.PaperKind = System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.A4;
            imagebrick = gr.DrawImage(pageimage, new RectangleF(1, 1, X - 22, Y - 10), BorderSide.None, Color.Transparent);
            HeaderReport(ROW[0, 8],ROW[0, 1], ROW[0, 2], X, Y);
            BodyReport(ROW, X, Y, Rowcount);
            ImageExportOptions ImageOption = printingSystem1.ExportOptions.Image;
            ImageOption.PageRange = "1";
            ImageOption.Format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            ImageOption.ExportMode = ImageExportMode.SingleFile;
            ImageOption.Resolution = 100;
            TextBrick2(TxtFooterEmail.Text, (float)0.170 * X, (float)0.949 * Y, (float)0.680 * X, (float)0.019 * Y, "B Nazanin", (float)10.5);
            if (Picload != string.Empty)
            {
                Image img = Image.FromFile(Picload);
                imagebrick = gr.DrawImage(img, new RectangleF((float)0.345 * X, 0, (float)0.280 * X, (float)0.150 * Y),
                    BorderSide.None, Color.White);
            }
            // Create a report instance. 
            gr.EndUnionRect();
            printingSystem1.End();            
            string FileName = @"Data\" +  DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString()+ " _"+  DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString()+ " _"+
                DateTime.Now.Second.ToString()+ ".jpg";// " _"+ "_"+ ROW[0, 8] +
            printingSystem1.ExportToImage(FileName);
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = FileName;
            process.Start();
            MyEmail.SendMailForYahyaee(TxtEmailfrom.Text, SearchemailAcount(ROW[0, 1], MainDataTable), TxtEmailPass.Text,
               FileName, Rowcount);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to open the image, why are you using Process.Start? That's what is opening your default image viewer program.